# asp.net login page inherit attribute c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

i keep getting this following error:

**ASPNET: Make sure that the class defined in this code file matches the 'inherits' attribute, and that it extends the correct base class (e.g. Page or UserControl).**

*it tells me the error is with the following: Login.aspx.cs    Line: 1*

```
Line 1:  using System;
Line 2:  using Entities;
Line 3:  namespace Pages.Account
```

**here is the code for my login.aspx file**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="Pages.Account.Pages_Account_Login" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Login: </b></td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtLogin" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
                    ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="txtLogin"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Password: </b></td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" 
                    ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="txtPassword"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" 
                    onclick="btnLogin_Click" /><br/>
                <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" 
                    PostBackUrl="~/Pages/Account/Registration.aspx">Register</asp:LinkButton>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</asp:Content>
```

here is the code for my login.aspx.cs file:

```
using System;
using Entities;

namespace Pages.Account
{
    public partial class Pages_Account_Login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            User user = ConnectionClass.LoginUser(txtLogin.Text, txtPassword.Text);

            if(user != null)
            {
                //Store login variables in session
                Session["login"] = user.Name;
                Session["type"] = user.Type;

                Response.Redirect("~/Pages/Home.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                lblError.Text = "Login failed";
            }

        }
    }
}
```

any help  would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Just to cover all bases, even though I don't think this is the problem, but if you've built this before, you may have an existing DLL in your BIN folder with an incorrect reference. Or maybe the problem is with the Master page, not the content page? Check both.

Answer (score 1):

I see the problem in your code; **Inherits** and **Code Behind Class** are different.

Ideally, class name should be -

```
public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    ...
}
```

and **Inherits** should be

```
<%@ Page ... CodeFile="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="Pages.Account.Login" %>
```

For Web Application Project, it should be **CodeBehind**.

```
<%@ Page ... CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="Pages.Account.Login" %>
```

Comment: i selected new website not new project when i starting building this. is it stil classed as a  project?

Comment: i now get the error could  not load type 'pages.account.login' when i try your solution.

Comment: Could you test with either `CodeFile="Login.aspx.cs"` or `CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs"`? One should work.  If still not working, could you upload the code github?

Comment: I now get this error which  makes no sense:    a ScriptResourceMapping for 'jquery'. Please add a ScriptResourceMapping named jquery(case-sensitive).]

Comment: It seem that the first issue was solved. ScriptResourceMapping is a different kind of error. Could you create a new question and post the exception?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong on the surface.

When I hit the voodoo asp.net errors.

I do the following:

1. Rename MyProblemPage.aspx to MyProblemPageOLD.aspx.
2. Create a new MyProblemPage.aspx.
3. REMOVE FROM PROJECT (do not delete) MyProblemPageOLD.aspx
4. Compile.  Should be no errors.
5. Move the code from aspx and .cs from MyProblemPageOLD.aspx, MyProblemPageOLD.aspx.cs
6. Compile.  It should work.
7. If it compiles now, delete MyProblemPageOLD*.*

I know its not a fix, but it will get you moving again.

Comment: How long did it take you to create the question?  This plan is better than nothing.  Especially when the pressure is on!

Comment: I now get a different error: System.InvalidOperationException: WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for 'jquery'. Please add a ScriptResourceMapping named jquery(case-sensitive).